# AlertDialog ,Checkbox should have a line between each other

Tags: java, android, checkbox, styles, android-alertdialog

I have an Alertdialog and style is Checkbox, I need to plus a line between each other.
Because I have too much items. 
thanks for help.

this is my code

```
public Button.OnClickListener IMBL = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AfterClick = new boolean[items.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < AfterClick.length; i++) {
            AfterClick[i] = false;
        }

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Daycarddd.this)
                .setTitle("skill")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, AfterClick,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < AfterClick.length; i++) {
                                        if (AfterClick[i]) {
                                        }

                                    }
                                } else if (seletedItems
                                        .contains(indexSelected)) {
                                    // Else, if the item is already in the
                                    // array, remove it
                                    seletedItems.remove(Integer
                                            .valueOf(indexSelected));
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton("confirm",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                for(int j=0;j< items.length;j++){                                           
                                    if(AfterClick[j]==true){            

                                    if(resultcheck==""){resultcheck=items[j];}else
                                      resultcheck =resultcheck+","+items[j] ;
                                    }
                                  } 
                                checkbox=resultcheck;
                                resultcheck="";
                                Toast.makeText(Daycarddd.this,
                                        checkbox,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("cancle",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                            }
                        }).create();
        dialog.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: show your xml code

Comment: @saint : I think you should create custom layout :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mhj2cqj5nmvlnu/13262127_1221895697830046_1137746837_o.png?dl=0   like this red line

Comment: why you need this red line??

Comment: beacuse i have 25 checkbox, But they are different class.

Comment: @saint then you have to create custom alert box with line .....

Comment: you need to create a custom alert dialog view i.e. xml, and add your RED line after every section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for drawing a horizontal line use this layout

```
     <View
           android:id="@+id/viewBorder"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />
```

// here inflate your custom dialog

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    final EditText edTxtAmount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edTxtOffer);
    builder.setTitle("Make Your Offer")
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // Clicked 'Okay'
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Clicked 'Cancel'
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

//custom layout

```
 <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/mCheckbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Your Check Box with border"/>
 <View
    android:id="@+id/viewBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/mCheckbox"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
```

// setView(view) will set your custom dialog view

Comment: How to add this view ?